# Common place for custom helper Matlab scripts and function?

Tags: repository, matlab

Matlab Central file exchange contains numerous helper scripts and functions. Is it possible to place them somewhere in order not to populate current (project) directory with helper files?

Answer (score 4):

There is set of functionality that concerns itself with *search path* ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/search-path.html)).

### [What Is the MATLAB Search Path?](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/search-path.html)

> The search path, or path is a subset of all the folders in the file system. MATLAB® software uses the search path to efficiently locate files used with MathWorks® products. MATLAB can access all files in the folders on the search path.

### [Add Folders to Search Path Upon Startup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/add-folders-to-search-path-upon-startup-on-unix-or-macintosh.html)

> The startup.m file is for specifying startup options. You can add folders to the search path by including addpath statements in startup.m. For example, to add the specified folders, /home/username/mytools to the search path, include this statement:
>
> ```
> addpath /home/username/mytools
> ```